# unity keep speed when object collides into a wall

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2.5D tank game. Currently the tank can move and shoot. However, when the bullet object collides with the wall it looses speed.

How can I get the bullet to maintain a set speed?

https://i.postimg.cc/FsZ9Jc4h/image.png

Comment: Hmm. If a bullet hits a wall, shouldn't it be stopped by it (or destroy the wall)? Can you be more specific about the intended behaviour here?

Comment: If you want your objects to bounce off the walls use proper [Physics Materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html)

Comment: I want the object to stay at a set speed. When it hits another object I dont want the speed its travelling at to change. Like a lazer beam when it gets reflected back at the same angle, it doesnt change speed.